# How to import font family in pyqt5?

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, pyqt, pyqt5

I searched too much but can't find any salution over the internet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> label=QLabel("hello",self)
> label.setStyleSheet("QLabel{font-size:50px;font-family:'Orbitron'}")

OR

> from PyQt5.QtGui import QFontDatabase label=QLabel("hello",self)
> QFontDatabase.addApplicationFont('file_name.otf or .ttf')
> label.setStyleSheet("QLabel{font-size:50px;font-family:'Orbitron'}")

Comment: Have you tested it, ensuring that the font is not installed? Qt only supports a *limited* set of CSS2.1, while `@font-face` is part of CSS3. Also, the fact that the font is otf or ttf is ininfluential, as that has nothing to do with stylesheets but the font loading capabilities of Qt (which supports both TrueType and OpenType). In order to correctly use a non installed font [`QFontDatabase.addApplicationFont`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfontdatabase.html#addApplicationFont) must be used.

Comment: @musicamante `@font-face` is also supported in CSS2.1. I searched but can't find this method of implementing non installed font so I used stylesheet Thanks for your help

Comment: No. @font-face was badly supported in CSS2, [removed in CSS2.1](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/changes.html#q21.104), and then reintroduced on [CSS3](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-fonts-3/#font-face-rule). Again, using it in Qt stylesheet is ininfluent, there's no trace of it in the source code (or any at-rule for what's worth), and using `addApplicationFont()` is the only supported way. If it works for you, it means that you already had the font installed and you simply used the wrong syntax in the first place. Also, please use appropriate [code formatting](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362).